# Retrieve specific or query data from online CSV file in Google Sheet without adding whole CSV data into sheet

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to Retrieve specific or query data from online CSV file in Google Sheet without adding whole CSV data into sheet. For example, a CSV file is stored in `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LazyGeniusMan/genshin-tc/main/data/characters/anemo/jean/stats.csv`, the CSV file content is something like this:

```
level,ascension,hp,atk,def,ascension_stat,ascension_value
1,0,1143.9840087890625,18.6200008392334,59.83000183105469,Healing Bonus,0
2,0,1238.934618241241,20.16545987895961,64.79588867364873,Healing Bonus,0
3,0,1333.8853640669404,21.71092113836289,69.76178264853479,Healing Bonus,0
...
19,0,2871.399851150665,46.736201928901664,150.1733040253639,Healing Bonus,0
20,0,2967.494634443574,48.30028405925759,155.19903079793949,Healing Bonus,0
20,1,3948.35748844748,64.26408448955544,206.49903003500003,Healing Bonus,0
21,1,4045.5959000870353,65.8467808318328,211.5845682083891,Healing Bonus,0
...
39,1,5808.475131076353,94.54020006523115,303.7825944112774,Healing Bonus,0
40,1,5908.002163144411,96.16014702812208,308.98782670921355,Healing Bonus,0
40,2,6604.931057187379,107.5028460790254,345.437827472153,Healing Bonus,0.055399999022483826
41,2,6703.313642667665,109.10416551193248,350.5832055755236,Healing Bonus,0.055399999022483826
```

Let's say I want to retrieve `3948.35748844748`, which have condition of `level=20` and `ascension=1`. So if possible, I need to get specific cell/column/row based on 1 or more condition, if not I'll try to add new column as identifier (column id).

I tried to use QUERY function but the column name is not detected, it says `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: hp`. The formula I used is:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LazyGeniusMan/genshin-tc/main/data/characters/anemo/jean/stats.csv), "SELECT `hp` where `level`=20 and `ascension`=1",0)
```

I can get column name detected by using `Col1`, `Col2`, etc as column name, but I need to make column name specific because I have many CSV files that have different column name.

Am I missing something that make column name can not be detected? is there a way to declare CSV first line as column name or something?

note: not sure if this relevant, the CSV file is generated using Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LazyGeniusMan/genshin-tc/main/data/characters/anemo/jean/stats.csv"), 
 "select Col3 where Col1 = 20 and Col2 = 1", 0)
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

try:

```
=DGET(IMPORTDATA(A5), "hp", {"level", "ascension"; 20, 1})
```

[image]

[image]

---

### update 2:

query solution via flipping the table and selecting columns we need to work with. then sorting column headers alphabetically and flipping it again so we would know to point out which column to filter

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(A5)), 
 "where Col1 matches 'hp|level|ascension'"))), 
 "select Col3,Col2 where Col1 = 1 and Col3 = 20", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried that as I mentioned in the question but I need to make the column name specific, because I have other CSV file that have different column name, remembering which column number for every CSV file is hard. So I prefer to use the first row as column name for query. Is it not possible ?

Comment: It works. Looks like it can only return single value ? is there a way to return row(s) and/or column(s) ? just like SQL `select`

Comment: @AndriyansyahNurrachman you can do:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(DGET(IMPORTDATA(A5), {"hp","level"}, {"level", "ascension"; 20, 1}))`

Comment: Could you also give an example to get rows and table ? I still dont understand how `ARRAYFORMULA` works. Let's say I want to (1) Get list of `level` 1 to 5; and (2) get table that have `level` and `hp` column, level 1 to 5 (2 column & 5 row, 6 row if the header is included)

Comment: @AndriyansyahNurrachman https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA509.png